# How would I re-implement a record with functions to separate data from logic?

Tags: functional-programming, elm

I have a `Planet` composed of two data files and a function

```
type alias OrbitDays = Float
type alias Birthdate = Date
type alias Birthday = Date
type alias NextBirthdayFunction =
    Birthdate -> Today -> OrbitDays -> Birthday

type alias Planet =
    { name : String
    , orbit : OrbitDays
    , next_birthday : NextBirthdayFunction
    }
```

I found *I highly encourage a strict separation of data and logic* at
https://github.com/elm/elm-lang.org/blob/master/pages/docs/records.elm

Have I brought some *OO-thinking* to Elm-programming in adding a Function to this record?

How could this be implemented using Elm's strengths?

Comment: What would be the problem with having it as a stand-alone function?

Comment: Why does `NextBirthdayFunction` take `OrbitDays` as a parameter?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with functions in records **iff** every record instance has its own function (implementation), and in that case they're even more powerful than normal OOP

Comment: @glennsl - different records can have different functions so using a "standalone function" would need some way to use the correct function with each instance of Planet

Comment: @Bergi NextBirthdayFunction performs some arithmetic involving an OrbitDays. I didn't know how the function could access `orbit` in a more direct way

Comment: @Bergi my `Planet` definition goes against the strong recommendation in the docs link I included in my answer. I understand the recommendation, so I'm trying to find out the way I would keep the two separate

Comment: It's hard to say much about how this could be implemented without knowing anything about how `NextBirthdayFunction` should work and could differ. But I suppose the most common solution would be to encode what might differ in a custom type that would be passed to the function telling it how to behave.

Comment: Also, putting functions in the model is perhaps even more discouraged, since functions can't be compared, which restricts certain kinds of optimizations and other operations you might want to do on a model.

Comment: @glennsl `NextBirthdayFunction` calculates a birthday on a planet given an earth birthdate, today's date & the length of time (in earth days) a planet takes to revolve around earth. I will learn about Custom types. I was trying to avoid needing a `case` to choose which function to use based on the value of Planet.name. It's always the same choice so putting it in a record felt nature. the website is live: 9birthdays.com

Comment: @Carl I'd understand the function takes in the orbit time of the planet (around the sun, presumably?), but what else does differ depending on the planet? You say the function would need to decide based on the planet name? That doesn't sound like a good idea

Comment: Only the planet's name and orbit length differ for each planet. I don't have to do a check based on planet name because I have a List Planet where I initialise next_birthday for each planet - that's hardcoded. this means I don't need a `case` statement which means less code. I'm now investigating Elm's custom types to try applying them

Comment: You said "*I was trying to avoid needing a `case` to choose which function to use based on the value of Planet.name*", but then you initialise `next_birthday` to the *same* function on all planets anyway? Like everyone said, don't make it part of the record then.

Comment: @Bergi I don't initialise next_birthday to the same function. I have a List Planet and one item uses a different function than the other eight - this is because Earth has a calendar with leap days etc. I'm reworking the code with a Custom type but it requires `case` statements - I'lll post a question asking how I can reduce the repetitive code in a `case`

Answer (score 0):

I took this approach:

```
type Planet
    = Earth Name
    | Alien Name OrbitDays
```

And then, functions used `case` to handle the two variants.
E.g.,

```
toBirthday : Planet -> Birthdate -> Today -> Birthday
toBirthday planet birthdate today =
    case planet of
        Earth _ ->
            nextEarthBirthday birthdate today

        Alien _ orbitDays ->
            nextAlienBirthday birthdate today orbitDays
```

This approach separated data from code which increased reuse while simplifying testing. It created a concept of Planet types documenting the different handling that Earth required from the other planets too.