# Can I pattern match an Elm custom type for all other variants?

Tags: types, elm

I have this custom type with a single instance:

```
type alias Name = String
type Planet
    = Mercury Name OrbitDays
    | Venus Name OrbitDays
    | Earth Name
    | Mars Name OrbitDays
    | Jupiter Name OrbitDays
    | Saturn Name OrbitDays
    | Uranus Name OrbitDays
    | Neptune Name OrbitDays
    | Pluto Name OrbitDays

planets : List Planet
planets =
    [ Mercury "Mercury" 88.0
    , Venus "Venus" 224.68
    , Earth "Earth"
    , Mars "Mars" 686.98
    {- , other planets -}
    , Pluto "Pluto" (247.7 * 365.25)
    ]
```

How can I write a function to return the `Name` of a given planet?
My first attempt is rather verbose:

```
toName : Planet -> String
toName planet =
    case planet of
        Mercury name _ ->
            name

        {- other planets -}

        Pluto name _ ->
            name
```

And I also need a format of code that can provide different handling for one value of planet to the other values.

Comment: Why do you have the planet name in each variant in the first place? Can `Pluto` be named anything other than `"Pluto"`?

Comment: There's also no point in having a custom type with payloads that are exactly the same across all variants. That just makes it more difficult to get to the data. Instead you for example define `Planet` as a custom type with no payloads (essentially an enum), and have a record containing `planet`, `name`, and `orbitDays`.

Comment: And if there's a one-to-one mapping between `planet` and `name`, which I'm guessing it is, you could skip `name` and just define a function `Planet -> Name` instead.

Comment: @glennsl let me edit my Question to make one Planet variant different. This will better match my application

Comment: @glennsl regarding Name... useful to know that one doesn't put Name data in Planet function but instead another function that uses `case` to return a string value for each variant. Could you explain why so I can know why I'm doing this?

Comment: It makes the relationship more clear (that it's one-to-one), puts strongly related definitions alongside each other and results in less code, because you won't have this repetition scattered around wherever you're going to create these.

Comment: @glennsl I had read `https://guide.elm-lang.org/types/pattern_matching.html` and saw `User` defined with `Regular` & `Visitor` variants, each with a String. I do understand your explanation. I'm now defining Planet to be `Home | Alien OrbitDays` and adding a function to return the name of the planet. That docs page doesn't give an example of how to access `age` which `Regular` lacks. Do you know how I'd access it?

Comment: It does show it, just doesn't use it. Read the "WIld Cards" section again.

Comment: Also, seems to me that `Home` also has `OrbitDays` (in reality), so why not make generalized functions that always take `OrbitDays` and skip this custom type entirely?

Comment: "Wild Cards" section - yes, I did read that. What I meant was that the docs skipped an example of how to handle access `age`. Might it be because it's tricky to access it?

Comment: You're right - earth does have an orbit (in reality). I was trying to document that the application didn't use it in the Elm code. This is why I had specified two different functions for `NextBirthdayFunction` in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72529419/how-would-i-re-implement-a-record-with-functions-to-separate-data-from-logic?noredirect=1#comment128147343_72529419 where @glennsl suggested the possibility of Custom types instead :)

Comment: thank you @glennsl you've been an enormous help. I've refactored to having `type Planet = Home Name | Alien Name OrbitDays` and this has remove the `case` handling I had in my Question and now documents the code handles earth differently to the other planets

Answer (score 2):

I had misunderstood the application of elm Custom Types.
They are less like enums than I had thought.

In this example, a more appropriate implementation would be:

```
type alias Name = String
type Planet
    = Home Name
    | Alien Name OrbitDays
```

This makes writing functions quite straightforward as each `case` is the handler for its "arguments". If the handling for two variants is always identical they are not different enough to warrant a Custom Type.

Re-reading the [docs](https://guide.elm-lang.org/types/pattern_matching.html) and @gennsl's comments to this question helped me get there.

Answer (score 1):

I have this feeling that you are dealing with static data here. However, variant payloads are capable of representing anything. Do you really want to have multiple name-period combinations for each planet?

Assuming no, the robust way is to just having a simple variant for each planet.

```
type Planet
    = Mercury
    | Venus
    | Earth
    | Mars
```

*Limiting to inner planets for the sake of brevity…*

Then if you want some static values, you get them through a function:

```
name : Planet -> String
name planet =
    case planet of
        Mercury -> 
            "Mercury"

        Venus -> 
            "Venus"

        Earth -> 
            "Home"

        Mars -> 
            "Mars"


orbitalPeriod : Planet -> Float
orbitalPeriod planet =
    case planet of
        Mercury -> 
            88.21

        Venus -> 
            264.08

        Earth -> 
            365.25

        Mars -> 
            811.89
```

Comment: thanks for your input - I understand your logic. I did have an error in my question (now corrected) - I'd shown Earth with an Orbit value but the type Planet didn't define Earth to have an OrbitDays. I'm currently using `type Planet = Earth Name | Alien Name OrbitDays` which prevents the code from treating Earth as an Alien planet. Given your answer, I see I should have a function to return planet names and a function to return OrbitDays. Currently, I have a function returning `List[Planet]`. More here: https://github.com/carlhunterroach/ninebirthdays

Comment: The same approach applies to discriminating earth as well. `isHome : Planet -> Bool`